# Under what conditions does $\log a^b=b \log a$ for complex numbers $a,b$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, intuition

> Under what conditions does $\log a^b=b \log a$ for complex numbers $a,b$ Use the branch of $\log$ with $-\pi< \theta <\pi$.
> For solve the problem I need understand the meaning of brach, and the definition of $\log z$ for $z\in \mathbb{C}$.

First of all I understand that given $z\in \mathbb{C} \setminus \lbrace 0 \rbrace $ we define $\log z=\log(|z|)+(arg(z)+2 \pi k)i$ for $k\in \mathbb{Z}$

Too I know that if $a,b\in \mathbb{C}$ we define $a^b=e^{b \log a}$ where $a\neq 0$.

Now for give a correct answer I need know the correct interpretation of the  **branch** of logarithm which I don´t understand.

according to my low skills in complex variable I Imagine that,first I should take the LHS
$$\log a^b=log(e^{b \log a})=b \log a$$ which is true for any $a,b\in \mathbb{C}, a\neq 0$.

Someone can give my a explanation about my mistake with my assumption, give me a step-by step solution or much better give me a intuitive and formally explanation of the meaning of **Branch of logarithm**

Comment: branch, not brach.

Comment: Thanks I fix the grammar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By one definition, $\log$ is an inverse function to $\exp$, i.e. $\log(z)$ should be a
number $w$ with $\exp(w) = z$.  The trouble is, there are infinitely many $w$ that work: $\exp(2 \pi i) = 1$, so if $\exp(w) = z$ then also $\exp(w + 2 \pi i k) = z$ for any integer $k$.  To be able to give a definite meaning to $\log(z)$, we have to make a choice from these infinitely many possibilities.  We can do it in such a way that $\log(z)$ is an analytic function on the complex plane with a curve starting at $0$ and going out to complex infinity removed.  Such a function is called a **branch** of the logarithm, and the excluded curve is called a **branch cut**.  If you choose the version of $\log(z)$ with imaginary part in $(-\pi, \pi)$, that's called the **principal branch**, and its branch cut is the negative real axis.

$a^b$ is defined, for complex numbers, as $\exp(b \log(a))$.  Again, in general that's ambiguous, so there are branches to consider.  The principal branch uses the
principal branch of logarithm.

Now $\log(a^b) = w$ where $\exp(w) = a^b = \exp(b \log(a))$, so $w = b \log(a) + 2 \pi i k$ for some integer $k$.  If you're using the principal branch of $\log$ (both for $\log(a^b)$ and $\log(a)$, the imaginary parts of both $w$ and $\log(a)$ must be in $(-\pi, \pi)$.  You want $k = 0$ according to your formula, so what you need is
that the imaginary part of $b \log(a)$ is between $-\pi$ and $\pi$.